# cant't query json data in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, json, ajax, vue.js

I'm making a adressbook app via laravel 5.2 and vuejs, my app needs CRUD functionality, i stuck at Update part, i  send the data via ajax to laravel
and i get the data in laravel but i cant update rows.
this is my method in vuejs that handle updating:

```
updatecontact:function(){
    var contactid = this.editingcontact.id;
    var contact update = JSON.stringify(this.editingcontact);
    this.$http({url: '/adressbook/'+contactid, data: {contactupdate} , method: 'PATCH'})
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    }, function (response) {
      // error callback
    });
```

and this the method that handles ajax request in laravel(it's a PUT)

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
     $adressbook = Adressbook::findorFail($id);
     $adressbook->save($request->all());
}
```

at last this is how the data looks like:

```
contactupdate: "{"id":5,"companyName":"poolad","zamineKar":"test","tel":"44044440","fax":"44044422","email"}"
```

Comment: Have you tried outputting what your laravel application receives? `dd($request->all());`.

Comment: While accessing from laravel are all your data in contact update envelope ?

Comment: @Jerodev it return this : array:1 [
  "contactupdate" => "{"id":5,"companyName":"poolad","zamineKar":"ریخته گری قطعات چدن و فولادی","tel":"44044440","fax":"44044422","email":"info@pooladcrusher.com","adres":"تهران میدان نور ساختمان گلها شرکت پولاد سنگ شکن","created_at":"2016-02-10 09:26:58","updated_at":"2016-02-10 12:30:16"}"
]

Comment: @nbin yes it is in a contactupdate

Comment: so why this happen when i want to update? i do the same for post request and my data is in a addcontact envelope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way to do it would just be to send `this.editingcontact` as the data:

```
updatecontact:function(){
  var contactid = this.editingcontact.id;
  this.$http({url: '/adressbook/'+contactid, data: this.editingcontact , method: 'PATCH'})
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  }, function (response) {
  // error callback
});
```

Then this update code should work:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
 $adressbook = Adressbook::findOrFail($id);
 $adressbook->update($request->all());
}
```

Comment: I tried both of your suggestions but it's not working, when i dd the save method it returns true but nothing changes.

Comment: it's working fine when i get data one by one like this: $adressbook->companyName = $request->input('companyName'). but i wonder why $request->all() doesnt work as well

Comment: One or more of your inputs may not be fillable.  in your model, you should have `$fillable = ['companyName',...];` for any fields you want to be able to fill using an array.  This should probably not include `id`.  So put the fields that you want to be fillable in your model then use `$adressbook->save($request->except('id'));`

Comment: the fillable was just fine, i tried except method and also send data without id variable, still the same i'm getting disappoint at why all() method not working

Comment: @moeinrahimi fix the casing on your findorFail method (should be `findOrFail($id)` and then try using the update method `$adressbook->update($request->all());`